# Custom wpf tab control with one permanent tab, all other tabs scrollable

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I need to create a control which has a single permanent tab ("home"), and all of the other tabs are scrollable.

Right now I am trying to achieve this result by subclassing the TabControl, adding an extra button (which looks like a tab) to the overridden template, and setting the `SelectedIndex` to `-1` whenever the button is clicked. When `SelectedIndex` is `-1`, a trigger causes the TabControl's ContentControl to be bound to a special "Home" tab's content. Basically, I am faking the behavior of a real tab and overriding the ability to deselect all tabs in doing so.

This seems to work, except for two problems:

1. Select example tab #3, then select home. THEN, try to select tab #3 again. Tab #3 doesn't respond.
2. Select tab #3, then select home. THEN, try to use the menu which happens to be in the same window. When I go to use the menu, #3 pops up as the selected tab again.

I've tried to listen to all kinds of events associated with the TabControl at this point, but none of them seem to give me something I can work with to get around these behaviors.

Is there something out there that will allow me to override the default `SelectedIndex` behavior? Should I be doing this another way? Ideally, I would like some way to take in a collection of tabs that allows me split up the tabs visually without losing the basic functionality of a TabControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement this by writing my own custom tab panel, as AresAvatar suggested. However, the panel needed to extend from the ConceptualPanel implementation from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ConceptualChildren.aspx. The problem is that the panel needs to have `IsItemsHost="true"` in the TabControl template to preserve the tabs' selection behavior. Unfortunately, once a normal panel is an items host, it's Children can't be changed from inside it's own class code. So, I couldn't add the scroll buttons that I needed. I was able to get around that problem with the ConceptualPanel by adding everything (tabs + scroll buttons) via AddVisualChild.

There might be a better way to do this, but this worked for me.

Comment: Also, I was able to avoid rewriting the ScrollViewer's functionality by simply writing an extra panel which extends the ConceptualPanel, passing the relevant tabs to it, then throwing the whole thing into a ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to accomplish this would be to use a custom ControlTemplate for the tab control.  You can use [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/) to get the current template.  The  that is part of that template would need to be replaced with a custom panel that you wrote.  You base that on Panel.  You would only need to override ArrangeOverride so that it arranged the Home tab in its place, and the others depending on the scroll position.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you essentially suggesting that I write my own TabPanel? I am already using my own ControlTemplate for the tab control.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.  If I understand your question correctly, it's the TabPanel behavior you are trying to override by always showing the Home tab no matter how the control is scrolled.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll look into it now and report back if I'm successful.

Comment: Is there a way I can put the InternalChildren for my custom tab panel into a ScrollViewer and then simply call Measure/Arrange on the ScrollViewer? I can mimic the functionality the existing TabPanel, but I can't figure out how to hand off my children another control... (I'm not even sure if this is the way to do it).

Comment: No.  WPF objects cannot have more than 1 parent.  It's very simple to define a custom panel with ArrangeOverride.  Here's one example: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control

Comment: Yeah, I understand how to write a basic layout panel. Are you saying that I need to write custom scrolling functionality for this particular panel? I was hoping to be able to use a ScrollViewer, as I already have the style defined for one.

Comment: I don't see how a ScrollViewer would work -- it would scroll everything, so yeah you'd have to add your own scrollbars, though that's not very complex.

Comment: I've written a custom panel which adds a repeat button between the first and second tabs. It works when not used inside a tab control, but as soon as I put the panel inside a tab control, my customizations are overridden, and only the tabs appear... T__T

Comment: @Amanduh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1432/discussion-between-aresavatar-and-amanduh)